# Unable to login into SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have been getting issues when trying to login into SQL Server.

The message I am getting is:

> Cannot connect to DESKTOP-1TB5LRR
>   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections (Provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error- 2)

Comment: As the error message says - have you verified you instance name and connection properties?

Comment: i reinstalled the software... its working fine now. thanks though :)